# Is there a way in Clojure Spec to assert that something must be a predicate

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

In Clojure Spec, is there a way to assert that something must be a predicate?

By predicate I mean a function which returns a true/false value.

I'd like to store some predicates in a collection. But is there a way to Spec this collection?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using `fspec`, with some caveats:

- You must specify an `:args` spec; not just a `:ret` spec. This could be an issue if the predicates have a variety of fixed arities, or might throw on invalid inputs e.g. `(pos? "1")`.
- Each predicate in the collection will be invoked several times each to ensure they conform to the spec.

If your predicates all take a single input, you could do something like this:

```
(s/def ::pred (s/fspec :args (s/tuple any?) :ret boolean?))
(s/def ::pred-coll (s/coll-of ::pred))
(s/valid? ::pred-coll [boolean? number?]) => true
```

To illustrate that the predicates will be invoked:

```
(defn one? [x]
  (prn x)
  (= 1 x))
(s/valid? ::pred-coll [one?])
nil
()
:tL
(#uuid "9023252f-d4fe-4ee5-b526-13835cd52187")
...
=> true
```

Comment: Hmmm... this looks plausible ... but then I wonder ... presumably the post condition is only checked when the function is called. So how can this ::pred check when I'm just putting the function into the collection? Does every function I try to put in have to explicitly have an fdef given to it?

Comment: @interstar there's no post condition involved in this example. I think this is becoming a question about how to prevent non-predicate functions from being _added_ to a collection? You could check `(s/valid? ::pred f)` before adding it, but it's up to you where/how to invoke spec to validate inputs. The predicate functions don't need `fdef`s, you just need them to conform to some `fspec`.